# I am looking for sampling software for the keyring 49?

Tags: software, logic-pro

I am wondering if anyone knows about sampling software for the keyring 49? I basically have loops that I made in Logic. I would like to use them with my keyring 49. I would like to turn my keyring 49 into a digital sampler. I would also like the loops to beat match or sync on the fly. All of my loops are the same BPM by the way. It is hard for me to beat mach them by ear on Logic ESX24 Sampler. The loops are .wav files. I would also like each key to be mapped separately. Is there any software out there for that?

Basically why I want this is, because I want to do live mixes with my Keyring 49.

Answer (score 1):

[Ableton Live](https://www.ableton.com/en/live/new-in-9/) is a program commonly used for live shows, as the name suggests, because you can set up several samples and launch them in various ways, like [using the MIDI output from your keyboard.](https://www.ableton.com/en/manual/midi-and-key-remote-control/)

It automatically syncs the tempo of the new samples you launch.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some popular software used for loop and sample based music creation. All these programs have convenient tools to map a MIDI keyboard to custom samples.

- [Ableton Live](https://www.ableton.com/)
- [Fruity Loops](http://www.image-line.com/flstudio/)
- [Reason](https://www.propellerheads.se/products/reason/)
- [NI Kontakt](http://www.native-instruments.com/en/products/komplete/samplers/kontakt-5-player/)
- [ACID](http://www.sonycreativesoftware.com/acidsoftware)